# Searching relational data

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2

This must be something obvious, but I'm struggling with this for over an hour.

I have `devices`, `laboratories` and `users` tables. Each device is bind to a `laboratory` via `lab_id` and each laboratory is bind to `users` via `user_id`. Each device is bind to only one laboratory and each user can be bind to many laboratories.

I want to display all devices from all labs, to which current user is bind. I thought, that this will be as simple as:

```
$query = Device::find()->with('lab')->where($[
    'lab.user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id
]);
```

But this fails with error, that there is no such column as `lab.user_id`. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the name of the relation function for labs in `Device`?

Comment: Relation name is `lab` (relation function's name is `getLab`) and table name is `labs`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use related data in your query, you should simply use [`joinWith()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail) instead of [`with()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#with()-detail) :

```
$query = Device::find()->joinWith('lab')->where([
    Laboratory::tableName() . '.user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id
]);
```

Comment: Relation name is `lab` (relation function's name is `getLab`) and table name is `labs`. Thanks, I'll check this once I'm back to my office, after weekend.